# Is there a way to control which item gets combined and which gets dropped?

Tags: teamfight-tactics

Yesterday this happened to me: I wanted to give a lvl 2  unit (lets say it's a Jax) its 3rd item which would be combined with the 3rd item already equipped. Now I had another lvl 2 Jax on the Bench, which, due to the time pressure, I gave the item, instead of the one being equipped already. Unfortunately I had another 2 lvl 1 Jax on my Bench, one being back from a shared draft round, so him having another item which I definitely don't want to combine with either of the other 2 items.

Now, assuming I have another Jax in my shop, **is there any way I can control which item would combine with which, and which would be dropped off, through means like bench order or positions in the field or something like this? Or would it happen at random?**

Comment: I think the only true control is by selling the Jax with the item you don't want to combine

Comment: @XtremeBaumer: Well, that's actually the question. I suspect, as long they didn't use a RNG extra for this, there will be some sort of ID'ing decide what items would combine. May it be the position of the units, items having first been equipped or even just the buy order of units (in which case, one could at least predict which items would combine and accordingly decide if they had to sell the unit with the unwanted item or just keep them as the item will drop out anyways). But of course you might be right in that, there being no such factor part of the decision.

Comment: @Zaibis I guess that to answer that there is only two solutions: test it yourself until you find out the logic behind fusion, or ask directly to Riot how it works.

Comment: @Zoma: Yeah, that comment would work for any and every question on this site "try it yourself or ask the developer." and would make this whole site useless. So not that much of a helpfull comment at all.

Comment: @Zaibis actually no, as there are lots of information that can be found written somewhere on the internet or IRL in books or manuals. If you want a different version of my previous comment: "Someone could experiment it or ask directly to developers then come back here with the answer.", hilighting how someone could expect to find the answer. I just sent a message to support to ask.

Comment: @Zoma: Ah, I see the try it >yourself< wording was a bit misleading what your intend was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sadly no**

As per an answer made by the Riot Games support, if there are more than two not already combined items when leveling up a champion, the game will not fuse them.

The leveled-up champion will equip with a random item of the non-fused items. The other items will be placed in your inventory, so you can re-use them later.
So there's still a chance that the item you *definitely don't want to combine with either of the other 2 items* is equipped on your Lv.3 Jax, thus forcing you to either combine it or leave it as it is (or sell your Lv.3 Jax, but I don't think it is what you want).

See below the screenshot of the french support answer (followed by my translation of it):
[image: Answer of the french support :<br>Le Jax gardera les deux objets complets + un objet partiel aléatoire.<br>Les deux autres objets partiles aléatoires reviendront sur le côté pour que tu puisses les utiliser.]

> Hello,
>   Jax will keep his two completed items + one non-complete random item.
>   The two other randoms non-complete items will be sent on the edge of the board so you can use them.
>
> Cordially
>
> "I like Troll but it has to never go too far"*
>   Callmespike, Player Support Specialist
>
> * <sub>Here's a wordplay that sadly don't pass through translation</sub>

Comment: Could you somehow add a reference to this?

Comment: @Zaibis I can include a screenshot of the supports' answer, but it's in French, so that's why I didn't include it at first. But if this is very important to you, I can add the screenshot and make the best possible exact translation of the answer.

Comment: That would be great, and I think would also improve the answer.

Comment: @Zaibis I'm going to work on this then.

Comment: @Zaibis After reading again the support answer, the answer seems pretty blur to me, so I'm going to ask more precisions to the support, to be sure that I well understand it.

Comment: @Zaibis The support finally answer me back, I'll edit my answer later or maybe tomorrow if I don't find the time tonight

Comment: Thanks for all the effort. Looking forward to it. Just leave me a ping. as soon you have don ite :)

Comment: @Zaibis Here's the update, please ask for clarifications if I'm nto clear enough.